# Understanding `children()` of `tr`

Tags: jquery, html, coffeescript

Given:

## HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='foo'>foo</td>
    <td class='a'>bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='here'></tr>
</table>
```

## CoffeeScript

```
row = $('.foo').closest('tr')
$.each row.nextUntil('.tr'), (i) -> 
    console.log 'i:', i 
    children      = $(this).children
    childrenWithA = $(this).children('.a')
    console.log 'children.length', children.length
    console.log 'childrenWithA.length', childrenWithA.length
```

I don't understand why `childrenWithA.length` evaluates to `0`, not `1`. I was expecting at least a single `child` with class = `a` due to `<td class='a'>bar</td>`.

```
i: 0
children.length 2
childrenWithA.length 0
```

Comment: Im not following what the `nextUntil(".tr")` is all about. By using `nextUntil(".tr")` your code will be skipping over the first `tr` (with the `.a` child) and instead starting at the following `tr` without.

Comment: I'm using `nextUntil` to modify `<td>`'s of a `<tr>` until a `<tr>` has a particular class.

Comment: OK, But the equivalent jQuery does not give the same output as you describe: https://jsfiddle.net/9c8zevdo/

Comment: `row.nextUntil('.tr')` will return `tr.here` which has no children. The output shown is not possible with this markup.

Comment: It's the number of arguments of the `children` function -> `typeof children === "function"`: https://jsfiddle.net/24s6L5mt/

Answer (score 1):

In CoffeeScript the rules for method calls are

- methods called with parameters, parentheses are optional

  ```
  object.method 1,2 
  object.method(1,2)
  ```
- Method calls without parameters *must* include the parentheses

  ```
  object.method()
  ```

You're missing parentheses from the call to `children`.

Once this is fixed - the coffeescript output gives thre same is the related jQuery only output: https://jsfiddle.net/Lt9qfdbc/

Note: You possibly want `addBack()` too, as per @Karl-André Gagnon answer, in order to include the first `tr` element

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `.nextUntil` doesn't include the element currently in the stack (in your case `tr`with `.a`).

If you want to include the current stack, you should use [`.addBack`](http://api.jquery.com/addback/).

You can see it working here : https://jsfiddle.net/9f3kcoq6/1/

Also note that `$.each` should be used when you loop a non-jQuery object or array. Else, use `row.nextUntil('.tr').addBack().each (i) ->`.

---

As for why `children.length` evaluate as `2`, see [@jamiec answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38103266/2324107).

**Additional note on it :** since `children`is assigned to a function, using `.length` return the number of arguments that function accept, hence why it return 2.

Comment: _That is because the .nextUntil doesn't include the element currently..._ That's correct but doesn't explain the output `0, 2, 0` which should be `0, 0, 0` instead if there are no children at all

Comment: @Andreas Jamiec explained it, but I added a note to explain it a little bit.